# how to represent negative number to array of integers?

Tags: java

I must convert string of 1324312321 to array of integers in java

this is fine. I could use integer parseint and string substring method

but how do I repesent -12312312 to my original array of integer..

the fact that - is a char / string and convert to array of integer would alter the value ( even though I convert - to integer-equivalent , it would change the rest of 12312312)

it must be an array of integers and how should I convert negative numbers and still keeep the same value

somehow reminding me of two complements trick but i dont think i need to go down to binary level in my program..

any other trick for doing this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just store the first element as `-1` instead of `1`?

Comment: or you could make them all negative

Answer (score 1):

Converting to an array of integers could mean many different things.  Why don't you just do?

```
String text = "-12312312";
int[] values = { Integer.parseInt(text) };
```

You haven't made it clear why you would want to create an array of integers when a single int is enough.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to provide a sign for all of the integers

```
+1+2+3+1+2+3+1+2
```

or leave a blank space for the positive integers

```
 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2
```

You could just say that a minus sign precedes any negative integer.  The example

```
1231-2312
```

would mean that the fifth integer in the array is -2.  If you want to represent an array of integers this way, you'd probably have to parse the string yourself, rather than using a string method.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways including:

- make the most significant digit negative,
- make all digits negative,
- add a leading digit (e.g. -1 versus 0) to represent the sign, or
- represent the sign separately from the array of digits.

Which is best depends on what it is you are going to do with the array of digits.  For example, if you need to represent non-significant leading zeros from the input string, then the first approach does not work ... there is no `-0` value.